# CMake, subdirectories and Google Test (mock) not linking properly. Tests not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a directory structure like this:

```
ProjectFolder
\--googletest (default google test layout)
|--source
|  \--test
|  |  \--CMakeLists.txt
|  |  |--test_Some.cpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--some.cpp
|  |--some.hpp
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--main.cpp (normal main)
|--maintest.cpp (empty)
```

ProjectFolder/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(ProjectFolder)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source
    ${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(source)

add_executable(ProjectFolderTest maintest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ProjectFolderTest source sourceTest gmock gmock_main)
```

ProjectFolder/source/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(source some.cpp)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

ProjectFolder/source/test/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(sourceTest test_Some.cpp)
```

This sadly does not work. `sourceTest` is never really linked (it seems). When I remove the `source` library from `target_link_libraries` I normally would expect undefined references but even that doesn't happen.
When I add a `#warning` to test_Some.cpp I do see the warning passing by.
If I remove `sourceTest` from `target_link_libraries` and add a hard reference to `add_executable` directly to `source/test/test_Some.cpp` I do get tests added and they run just fine.

How do I get this to work using `add_subdirectories` without having to add all the files in one CMakeLists.txt? Or what should I be doing different overall?

(Just trying to learn how to use CMake). I can't use the proposed option to download googletest from the interwebs using `ExternalProject` because I am evaluating CMake for a project where we have to have specific versions inside our own VCS.

Comment: note: ExternalProject can point to your googletest version in your custom VCS, i.e. you put anything you want in the url...

Comment: You don't need ugly include_directories() gtest and gmock target will provide the needed include directory for you

Comment: Seems strange that sourceTest doesn't need to `target_link_libraries(sourceTest PRIVATE source)`.
I think sourceTest should be am `add_executable()`
then use `add_test(NAME ProjectFolderTest COMMAND sourceTest)` (this will automatically see that sourceTest is the previous executable -> add the necessary dependencies...), also if you depend on gmock_main you don't need to provide a maintest.cpp I guess...
and use include(CTest) to run all test (i.e. several binaries if any)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure, but it might be connected to this [issue](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/481).

Since you didn't post your tests source code I cannot really tell, if your solution should work or not, however I strongly recommend the following structure:

```
ProjectFolder
|--googletest (default google test layout)
\--source
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--main.cpp (normal main)
|  |--some.cpp
|  |--some.hpp
\--test
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--maintest.cpp (not empty)
|  |--test_Some.cpp
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

Then, the test's `CMakeLists.txt` might look like this:

```
enable_testing()
set(MY_TEST_FILES maintest.cpp
    test_Some.cpp)
add_executable(ut-myTest ${MY_TEST_FILES})
target_link_libraries(ut-myTest gmock SomeOtherLibrary)
add_test(MyTest ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/ut-myTest)
```

And your test's main should look like this:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

EDIT =====

Just a clarification: `add_test` directive just allows you to run your tests with `make test`. You can still use your tests without it, just by executing the binary `ut-myTest`.